# Как передать одни и те же переменные всем шаблонам?

Tags: twig, php

Всем привет.

Второй день изучаю шаблонизатор Twig, и возник вопрос: как передать одни и те же переменные всем шаблонам? Например, у меня везде используется переменная  `{{ home }}`, и в каждом файле для нее передавать значение - это полный бред.

В Smarty было проще: создал файлик `smarty.php`, в нем передал все нужные переменные вида `$smarty->assign('home',$home);`, подключил этот файлик к движку - и все хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как гласит [легенда](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals),

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('myvar', $myGlobalVar));
```

Comment: Не знал, что и так можно. Но уже везде сделал по своему.

Comment: Для новичка в symfony.. А куда лучше вставить этот код и что за `$loader`?

Comment: @jekaby, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/api.html#loaders

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, это передать необходимые значения в php-переменную `$_SESSION`
Но здесь надо учитывать ограничение передаваемых данных таким способом.

Например:

```
$_SESSION['HOME'] = 'значение переменной';
```

А дальше в любом файле можно получить значение этой переменной следующим образом:

```
$value = $_SESSION['HOME'];
```

**UPDATE**

В Twig создание глобальных переменных, которые видны во всех шаблонах, делается так:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        ga_tracking: UA-xxxxx-x
```

Теперь, переменная `ga_tracking` будет доступна во всех шаблонах Twig:

```
<p>Our google tracking code is: {{ ga_tracking }} </p>
```

Comment: Значит аналога $smarty->assign в Твиге нет?

Comment: Обновил свой комментарий, смотри UPDATE

Comment: Это вы взяли отсюда http://symfony-gu.ru/documentation/ru/html/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

Но у меня не фреймворк Symfony2

Comment: Да, вы очень догадливый! И советую вам еще почитать вот это: http://symfony-gu.ru/documentation/ru/html/reference/dic_tags.html#reference-dic-tags-twig-extension 
Тут вы поймете как передавать объекты в глобальной переменной!

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал по-другому: в подключаемом везде файле `$core = array(тут все мои переменные);`
Потом `echo $twig->render('setting/index.twig', array('core' => $core, 'arrayrowskin' => $arrayrowskin));`

и в шаблоне вот так: `{{ core.home }} или {{ core.setup.copy }}`